# Can't read big pdf file with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, xmlhttprequest

I have simple XMLHttpRequest to php server script.

```
    fxhr.onload = function (data) {
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data.target.response));
    var string = JSON.parse(data.target.response).data.content;
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.target.response));
    DEFAULT_URL = convertDataURIToBinary(string);

    var config = getViewerConfiguration();
    window.PDFViewerApplication = pdfjsWebLibs.pdfjsWebApp.PDFViewerApplication;
    pdfjsWebLibs.pdfjsWebApp.PDFViewerApplication.run(config);
  };
  fxhr.open('POST', window.location.pathname + 'content');
```

Code of server script:

```
      public function execute()
{
  $productModel = new shopProductModel();
  $bookModel = new shopEbooksPluginItemModel();
  $item = $productModel->getByField('url', waRequest::param('product_code'));
  $bookFile = $bookModel->getByField(array(
   'product_id' => $item['id'],
   'book_type'  => waRequest::param('reader_state')
  ), false);
  $content = @file_get_contents($this->getBookFullPath($bookFile));

  $this->response = array('content' => $this->getBaseEncodedFile());
}

private function getBookFullPath($bookFileRow)
{
  return $bookFileRow['file_path'] . $bookFileRow['file_name'];
}

private function getBaseEncodedFile($content)
{
  return 'data:application/pdf;base64,' . base64_encode($content);
}
```

If i try read little pdf files it's work good, but if i try read 40mb pdf file server response have only "data:application/pdf;base64,".
file_exists returning true.

Comment: Are there any messages in `error_log` that might help?

Comment: Hm maybe i try check

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a couple settings in the `php.ini` file that could be causing your problem.

`memory_limit` -- This is almost certainly the problem; PHP must load all the data into memory in order to process it.  Try increasing this value to 50% more than the largest size file you expect to process.

`max_execution_time` -- if the script takes a long time to process all the data, it will be killed.  Try increasing this value.

I have often had to modify those limits in `php.ini` to allow scripts to handle large amounts of data.

Comment: `memory_limit 128`
`max_execution_time 180`
It's return null instantly

Comment: `memory_limit 128` means 128 **bytes**.  Try `memory_limit 128M` for 128 **megabytes**

Comment: and it's didnt help